# confused on one-hot encoding output

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Confused why final output is `[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]`?

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> enc = OneHotEncoder()
>>> enc.fit([[0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]])  
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype=<... 'numpy.float64'>,
       handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=True)
>>> enc.n_values_
array([2, 3, 4])
>>> enc.feature_indices_
array([0, 2, 5, 9])
>>> enc.transform([[0, 1, 1]]).toarray()
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your training data:

```
  A    B    C    # <== feature names
  0    0    3
  1    1    0
  0    2    1
  1    0    2
```

Now as you see in `enc.n_values_`: `array([2, 3, 4])`

The first feature A has two possible values = 0 and 1.
Similarly feature B has three possible values = 0, 1, 2
...

Now in the output, each feature will be assigned number of columns according to the above values.
Something like this:

```
A_0   A_1   B_0   B_1   B_2   C_0   C_1   C_2   C_3
```

Here A_0 means that 0 is present in data. So, A_0 will be 1 (hot) and A_1 will be 0. If 1 was present in that data, then A_1 will be 1 (hot) and A_0 will be 0.

So for input:
  A  B  C
 [0, 1, 1]

Here, A=0, so A_0 will be 1 and rest A_1 will be 0.
for B, B=1, so B_1 will be 1 and others (B_0 and B_2) will be 0. Same for C.

So final output is:

```
A_0   A_1   B_0   B_1   B_2   C_0   C_1   C_2   C_3
 1.,    0.,  0.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   0.
```

Please see this for more information: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features